# How can I create a preview box for my text input, taking into account font and colour

Tags: html, product-page

I need to create a preview box for my text. A good example can be found on the website below. It takes the user input and generates a PNG of what it would look like.

How would I be able to do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imagestring` from php. For more details and examples, you can follow this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Good luck !